# Disjoint cycle permutations

Tags: permutations

Work out the decomposition in disjoint cycles.

I am working on disjoint cycles. I sometimes get confuse, so can anyone please check my work.

A) $(13)(2345) $

I am starting from right to left
So $2$ goes $3$, and $3$ goes to $1$. $(21)$

Then $3$ goes to $4$ since there is no $4$ on the left, then I will have $(13)(2345) = (21)(345)$

and for F) $(12)(13)(14) = (14)(32)$

Are my answer correct. 
Thank you

Comment: Your answer can't be right since $\;1\rlap{\;\;/}\rightarrow 2\;$ . And what is "f)"

Comment: f) is the exercise. The exercises are list in letters rather than numbers.

Comment: And how are we supposed to guess that, @Naye?

Answer (score 1):

As you say (and most authors say), from right to left:

$$(13)(2345) \longrightarrow\begin{cases}1\to 3\\3\to 4\\4\to5\\5\to2\\2\to3\to1\end{cases}\;\implies (13)(2345)=(13452)$$

Comment: I thought left was (left)(right) rather than starting (right)(left)

Comment: @Naye, I've no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

When working with cycles, you need to continue with the last value done and keep going until the cycle actually cycles back on itself. You can't assume that you end up with disjoint cycles.

For (a), you've got $(21)$ so far. Instead of jumping to $3$, you need to find out what happens to $1$. So $1\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 3$, so now the cycle is $(213)$. Now do $4$ and $5$ to get the final answer of $(21345) = (13452)$. Note that you should check $5$ actually goes to $2$ as a double-check that things have worked out correctly.

For (f), you've got the numbers in a correct order but you don't end up with disjoint cycles. It is just a single cycle.

Comment: Why is (21345) = (13452)? Is it because they are commute

Comment: It is just a reorder of the terms. As long as items continuing moving in the right order, you can rewrite it however you like. So $(21345) = (13452) = (34521) = (45213) = (52134)$. We generally right the smallest number in each cycle first.